# Comparing column sets in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, list, pyspark

I have two lists of columns say e.g. listA and listB.
ListB is subset of listA.

I want to check if all the columns in listB are present in listA or not and on the basis of this comparison I want to do some operation.

Is there any option we can do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Yogesh Sharma, could you please add a code snippet into your question so we know what you are trying to achieve and what you are struggling with.

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma Did my answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a pyspark problem but rather a python problem:

Option 1: develop a basic function to do so. The idea is that you stop your search as soon as an element of listA has been proven not to be contained in listB.

```
def containsAllOf(listA, listB):
    for (e in listA):
        if (!listB.contains(e)):
            return false
    return true
```

Also this solution can be written like this (it's more elegant but the first option might tell you sooner if a given list is NOT contained in the second).

```
def containsAllOf(listA, listB):
    len([x for x in listA if x in listB]) == len(listA)
```

Option 2: use pyton functions (set theory). The idea: if listA inner join listB == listA, then all elements of listA are contained in listB for sure.

```
def containsAllOf(listA, listB):
    length(list(set(listA) & set(listB))) == length(listA)
```

I'm not sure which option would fit you best, you need to test. It depends on the sizes of both your lists. But the first option already has quite a decent algorithmic complexity O(n). The second one is a bit more complicated to predict, but it can be O(n log(n)) depending on the underlying complexity of merging two sets in Python.

If this solves your problem, do not hesitate to upvote.